# makeEwsRequestAsync failed (Outlook OWA Add-in)

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I have a very simple OWA Add-In which is working fine when the mail size is < 1 MB. But when mail size increases like adding attachments then, I am getting error - **makeEwsRequestAsync failed. [object Object]**

I went through some post for the solution but didn't found any solution for this. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: This is the known limitation of makeEwsRequestAsync and it is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#makeEwsRequestAsync_data__callback__userContext_  .Try to make request from back-end instead of API

Answer (score 0):

This is the known limitation of makeEwsRequestAsync and it is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#makeEwsRequestAsync_data__callback__userContext_.Try to make request from back-end instead of API –